# Databricks : tablesample only using certain groups

Tags: sql, random, databricks, sample

I have a table in databricks with ~500 million rows covering 25 months of data (2018-2020).  I want to pull a 1 million row sample for some quick analysis & modeling.  When I use `tablesample(1000000 rows)` or `limit 1000000` only 8 of the 25 months are represented in the sample.  Is there a way to fix this?

```
%sql
with c1 as(
  select *
  from my_table
  TABLESAMPLE(1000000 ROWS)
)
select month_id, count(*) cnt
from c1
group by month_id
order by month_id
```

Returns 8 rows all in the last 8 months of the data set.

```
%sql
with c1 as(
  select *
  from my_table
  limit 1000000
)
select month_id, count(*) cnt
from c1
group by month_id
order by month_id
```

Returns 8 rows all in the last 8 months of the data set.

```
%sql
with c1 as(
  select *
  from my_table
  --TABLESAMPLE(1000000 ROWS)
  --limit 1000000
)
select month_id, count(*) cnt
from c1
group by month_id
order by month_id
```

Returns 25 rows covering all months

Answer (score 1):

how about :

```
select * from (
    select * , row_number() over (partition by month_id order by rand()) rn
    from my_table
) t
where rn <= 1000000
order by month_id
```

Comment: I get a message that DISTINCT window functions are not allowed

Comment: @screechOwl  well that was for calculating number of rows you want , you can change 1000000 divided by number of month you have so you have equal number of rows  in each group . because right now , the query will return (1000000) * ( number of month you have in the data) rows. see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Databricks TABLESAMPLE docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-sampling.htm):

> Always use TABLESAMPLE (percent PERCENT) if randomness is important. >TABLESAMPLE (num_rows ROWS) is not a simple random sample but instead is >implemented using LIMIT.

I don't know why TABLESAMPLE and LIMIT together in your lower example caused a different result but I would use PERCENT instead of ROWS:

```
%sql
with c1 as(
  select *
  from my_table
  TABLESAMPLE(0.2 PERCENT)
)
select month_id, count(*) cnt
from c1
group by month_id
order by month_id
```